# $.ajax error cannot catch thrown exception from php

Tags: php, jquery, exception

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "functions/add_vendor.php",
    data:
    {
        vendor_info_json : vendor_info_json
    },
    success:function(result)
    {
        alert('Successfully Done.')
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Error Message: '+ textStatus);
        alert('HTTP Error: '+ errorThrown);
    }
})
```

This is the jquery code I'm working on. And the following is the add_vendor.php file being called.

```
<?php
include_once('../models/VENDOR_DB_MANAGER.php');

$vendor_info_json = $_REQUEST["vendor_info_json"];
$DB = new VENDOR_DB_MANAGER();
$DB->connectTo('BBY');
try
{
            //This ALWAYS returns false to test the code.
    if($DB->insertDataToTable('mfVendor', $vendor_info_json))
    {
        $DB->disconnect();

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $data = json_encode($result);
        echo $data;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Error has been detected.");

    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            echo "Exception occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Ok, That 'if($DB->insertDataToTable('mfVendor', $vendor_info_json))' part always is false to test $.ajax's error handling code. No matter what I do, error: callback is not working even if the php code throws an exception all the time.

What are the problems I'm missing here?  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your server throws an Internal Server Error, from Javascript side it's still a success. In your `success` function you have to check the response's status code, and handle it accordingly.

Comment: I see... On the javascript side, it actually 'succeeded' passing info to php and that's why it's considered to be a success?  Never thought about it that way... I will accept your answer after 6 mins! Thank you!

Comment: This is definitely not a behavior I see. WIth jQuery 1.9.1, any PHP throw would make the jQuery's .fail() callback (which replaced the .error) fire up, and NOT the .done() one (.done replaced the .success).