# Print exception in Ajax thrown from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a POST request to a Url using Ajax. My JS/JQuery code looks like this

```
var params = {
    'username' : 'eddard.stark@got.com',
    'name' : 'Eddard Stark'
};
$.post("/user/add", params, function(data) {
    // no errors
    var user = eval('(' + data + ')');
    $("#spanId").html("User Id " + user.id);
    // Here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472116/ajax-error-cannot-catch-thrown-exception-from-php 
    // they are saying that it can be handled here. But How?
}).fail(function(err, status) {
    // error 4xx : client side errors (e.g. controller/action does not exist)
    // error 5xx : server side errors (like db failure)
    $("#spanId").html("Error " + err);
}).always(function() {
    $(elm).hide();
    $('#spanId').show();
});
```

PHP code for `/user/add` action is

```
function add() 
{
    $username = null;
    $name = null;
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (isset($_POST['username']) { $username = $_POST['username']; }
        if (isset($_POST['name']) { $name = $_POST['name']; }
    }
    if (is_null($username) || is_null($name)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid request');
    }
    $user = $this->User->search($username);
    if (isset($user)) {
        thorw new Exception('User not available');
    }
    // ... more code ...
}
```

**How can I print those exceptions in Ajax?**

---

**Edit**:
There is another way to handle this. Set below header before throwing an exception

```
header("HTTP/1.1 400 User not available");
// throw exception
```

Then `fail` handler from my Ajax code can print it like

```
$("#spanId").html("Error : " + err.statusText)
```

But I don't want to do this. I want to print it in `success` handler itself.

Comment: create a variable $exception. In your exception ifs, change the value of $exception as necessary. Then send your $exception to ajax with your other already-there variables. Then check the value of $exception in ajax and deal with them as necessary

Comment: see here:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809963/handling-php-exceptions-with-jquery to get an answer

Comment: Why exception is not considered an error? Is there another handler for it?

Answer (score 0):

here a little demonstration of my comment.

in your ajax

```
.done(function (response) { 


                if( (response.exception) === "noExp" )
                {
                        alert("success!!!");
                        //no exception
                }
                else
                {
                        //handle it
                }
}
```

in php

```
function add() 
{
    $username = null;
    $name = null;
    $exception = "noExp";
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (isset($_POST['username']) { $username = $_POST['username']; }
        if (isset($_POST['name']) { $name = $_POST['name']; }
    }
    if (is_null($username) || is_null($name)) {
        //throw new Exception('Invalid request');
        $exception = "invalid request";
    }
    $user = $this->User->search($username);
    if (isset($user)) {
        //thorw new Exception('User not available');
        $exception = "User not available";
    }
    // ... more code ...
    $result = array(
        "exception" => $exception,
         //other returns
    )
    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

Comment: But there is `// ... more code ...` that I don't want to run when an exception occurs. When I `throw new Exception` further processing halts. Which is exactly what I want. I can't `echo` and `throw new Exception` at the same time

Comment: @HussainTamboli you can always put the `echo` inside the ifs and do a `return;`

Comment: or if you are looking for a more generic way, you should use a global exception handler. its usage is shown in link @Sudhir provided.